# Determine existing file access permissions on Android Q

Tags: android, android-ndk, file-access, android-10.0, storage-access-framework

I am reading and writing to files and directories from native C++ code. The standard way for getting file access is to use the Storage Access Framework in Java and then use the file descriptor in the native code (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/media#native-code):

```
// Called from native code:
public void requestFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public native myNativeCallbackFunction(int fd, ...);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
        int resultCode, Intent resultData) {

    Uri uri = resultData.getData();
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    int fd = parcelFd.detachFd();
    myNativeCallbackFunction(fd, "other information identifying the file such as the file name");
}
```

The returned Uri from `onActivityResult` can be stored and re-taken so that we do not have to prompt the user each time (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#permissions):

```
final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
            & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
// Check for the freshest data.
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

But there are some locations (such as `app.package/files` for instance) which can be accessed without the SAF:

1. Is there a way to determine if a file/directory can be accessed without SAF and without having the stored Uri from a past `onActivityResult` result?
2. Is there a more beautiful way of transferring the file descriptor to native code than using the `myNativeCallbackFunction` function approach?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Remove that line. It makes no sense. You cannot grant anything there.

`getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs()` are the places where you can still use the classic File classes.

Further: In principle you dont have to store the obtained uris as with `getPermanentUriPermissions()` you can always see them.

But if you have more than one permission you will not know which one is for which. So storing self is needed too.